# How to use Prepared Statement in Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

I created a simple insert statement in Laravel 5.2 like these.

```
User::create([
        'email' => $request->input('email'),
        'username' => $request->input('username'),
        'password' => bcrypt($request->input('password')),
    ]);
```

But I want my database more secure so I prefer using Prepared Statement. I'm asking to properly write the syntax? How can I properly hash my `password` within statement?

```
User::insert('insert into users (email, username, password) values (?,?,?)');
```

Comment: Eloquent ORM takes care of these security issues. To make a hash use `Hash::make()`

Comment: @Daan in my first statement is this already secured?

Comment: Yes @Francisunoxx only change this `'password' => bcrypt($request->input('password'))` to `'password' => Hash::make($request->input('password'))`

Comment: @Daan what's the difference between `'password' => Hash::make($request->input('password'))` with `'password' => bcrypt($request->input('password'))`? Although my first statement already hash my password?

Comment: Both `bcrypt('password')` and `Hash::make('password')` are OK according to the documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/hashing. Choose whichever you prefer.

Comment: @Francisunoxx None actually, I just prefer to use Laravel's `Hash` class

Comment: Appreciated your tips! :)

Answer (score 9):

Eloquent does that for you behind the scenes, after doing all its fancy stuff, in the end, Eloquent calls `PDO::prepare()`, `PDO::bindValue()` and finally `PDO::execute();`.

Go through the code of `Illuminate\Database\Connection` to get the gist of it.

The only thing you need to be careful about is not to use `DB::raw()` with directly provided user input, for example:

```
// This is bad
DB::raw('SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE col = '.$request->query('col'));

// This is good
DB::raw('SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE col = ?', [$request->query('col')]);
//or
DB::raw('SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE col = :col', ['col' => $request->query('col')]);
```

Comment: I think you meant `DB::select` rather than `DB::raw`, the latter returns a SQL expression and it doesn't have a second arg for the bindings, but the former executes the statement.  https://github.com/illuminate/database/blob/5.2/Connection.php#L284
Everything else is fine!